# Android PreferenceActivity without XML

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to create Holo-styled (non-deprecated) PreferenceActivity and it's headers/fragments in pure Java, not XML? Is it possible to add and remove headers programmatically?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! can you tell us what you've tried so far? perhaps some searches you've tried and why they weren't effective? This will help answerers as they know what you've looked for and will help you becuase they will hopefully solve your problem quicker :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create/add your own Headers in OnBuildHeaders, and then check ids in onHeaderClick:

```
@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    //loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.prefs_sync_plugins, target);

    Header customHeader = new Header();
    customHeader.titleRes= R.string.customHeaderTitle;
    customHeader.id = R.string.customHeaderTitle;
    target.add(customHeader);
}

@Override
public void onHeaderClick(Header header, int position) {
    if (header.id == R.string.customHeaderTitle) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to create Holo-styled (non-deprecated) PreferenceActivity and it's headers/fragments in pure Java, not XML?

Your `onBuildHeaders()` method can presumably create `PreferenceActivity.Header` objects by other means. You might want to create a test project that does headers via XML and dump the contents of the resulting `Header` object(s) to confirm that you will populate yours correctly, since the documentation for `Header` is a bit terse.

> Is it possible to add and remove headers programmatically?

There is an `invalidateHeaders()` method on `PreferenceActivity` that looks promising. Through examining the source code, it looks like calling that will trigger another call to `onBuildHeaders()`, where you would provide the new list, much like `invalidateOptionsMenu()` triggers a call to `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.